# Pull all records only if 3 dups or more exist

Tags: sql, duplicates

I'm trying to pull ALL fields and records if two of the fields (category and measure) create 3 or more dups.

```
SELECT category
      ,measure 
      ,date
FROM my_table
```

for example:

```
category measure date
EVENTS   COL     04/15/2014
EVENTS   COL     05/21/2014
EVENTS   COL     07/16/2014
```

So the above meets the criteria of 3 or more so we would pull all three.

```
category measure rec_count
EVENTS   COL     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like - gives you all rows with 3 or more records

```
SELECT 
  category,
  measure,
  date 
FROM 
  my_table t1 

  inner join (
    SELECT 
      category,
      measure
    FROM 
      my_table
    group by
      category,
      measure
    having
      count(*) >= 3
  ) t2 on
    t2.category = t1.category and
    t2.measure = t1.measure
```

To get only the count you would run

```
    SELECT 
      category,
      measure
      count(*)
    FROM 
      my_table
    group by
      category,
      measure
    having
      count(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT category
  ,measure 
  ,count(*) as rec_count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY category, measure
HAVING count(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    category, measure, date, count(*) cnt
FROM my_table
GROUP BY category, measure
HAVING cnt >= 3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not group your results.

```
SELECT q.* FROM
    (SELECT
    category
    ,measure 
    ,date
    ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY category,measure) [rec_count]
    FROM
    my_table) q
WHERE q.rec_count >= 3
```